# Sci-fi book or short story about people who crash-land on an alien world. The protagonist is captured by a hive of intelligent insects

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books, aliens

This book from my teenage years I just can't get out of my mind for many years now, and sooo want to reread!

It involved a travelling spaceship full of a few key characters - a male and a villain (I think an Asian female from some sort of sinister government role..perhaps called Zhou?)

The ship crash-lands on an alien world that was sort of 'protected' by some otherworldly pandimensional alien species, referenced in the past but of which we know almost nothing..

The world however is full of vicious native animal creatures, and the protagonist (with some help?) ventures along a river fighting off or avoiding the native fauna using his earlier special training along the way..

More interestingly, it later involves the protagonist being captured by a hive of highly intelligent advanced insects -  who proceed to eat some of his previous crew members (followers of his enemy?) who resist, and by analysing their DNA work out both humanity's ancestral evolutionary past, and how to better "communicate" with humans, producing a sort of drug to help the humans 'see' better...

The drug however greatly enhances the protagonist's mental abilities far beyond that of any human, allowing him not just to communicate with the insects, but control them..and provides him with growing mental powers..

The protagonist then uses these powers to transport himself into a higher plane of existence...

Only to be captured in another dimension by a giant, 40 foot high advanced AI robotic creature (that was once biological many eons ago), who scientifically studies and mentally interrogates him like a animal - determined to find out which universe he came from and how to escape its own dying system, to return to his new younger one (later with its species, of course!)...

Which it eventually manages to do, and he escapes back, somehow summoning the hyperdimensional alien protectors (the ones that had protected the planet he had crashed on) - who destroy the robotic AI as it enters our universe - causing a massive explosion in the process..

It was an incredibly interesting read, and I just can't get it out of my head...more so in that I now actually understand science, evolutionary biology, DNA and medical matters to a far better degree now..!!

Note : It might have been a short story - I am not sure...

Ive tried searching for this title for years - without any success...

Hoping someone here may know..!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this book or short story, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: Ummm....Im not that old....! say 1980s maybe 1990s..?
I thought it was published around the same time..

Comment: This kind of resembles _[Serpent's Reach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpent%27s_Reach)_ by CJ Cherryh. It's in the right time frame, at least. The (human) protagonist is female, however.